# How to Execute a Python Script in Notepad++?

Tags: python, notepad++

I prefer using Notepad++ for developing,

How do I execute the files in Python through Notepad++?

Comment: You might find http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/698915-python-notepad helpful.

Comment: [I made a small setup guide for NppExec.](https://gist.github.com/CTimmerman/3fc259d7867c38f6919e)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

#### First option: (Easiest, recommended)

Open Notepad++. On the menu go to: Run -> Run.. (F5). Type in:

```
C:\Python26\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Now, instead of pressing run, press save to create a shortcut for it.

***Notes***

- If you have Python 3.1: type in `Python31` instead of `Python26`
- Add `-i` if you want the command line window to stay open after the script has finished

---

#### Second option

Use a batch script that runs the Python script and then create a shortcut to that from Notepad++.

As explained here: http://it-ride.blogspot.com/2009/08/notepad-and-python.html

---

#### Third option: (Not safe)

> The code opens “HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore”, if the key exists it will get the path from the first child key of this key.

Check if this key exists, and if does not, you could try creating it.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the help so far.

I tried option 2, that didnt work. It said :

http://i37.tinypic.com/b4fhfm.jpg

On Windows 7, this might be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you have spaces in the path to the file that it's trying to open, and your script doesn't put double quotes around it.

Comment: Open Notepad++. On the menu go to: Run -> Run.. (F5). Type in: cmd /K "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"

Comment: I don't understand the shortcut thing.  I save it and give it a shortcut combination, but then it won't run just by pressing those keys.  What am I doing wrong?  I can make it a plugin command and use it when the console window is selected.  But that completely defeats the point.

Comment: While this answer (#3) seems to be the most common one I've found on the web, it doesn't work well for me. The problem is that it runs everything in the Notepad++ directory. Thus, I've come up with the following solution:

**cmd /c "taskkill /F /IM python.exe & cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) & C:\Python27\python.exe -i "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(FILE_NAME)""**

This runs the code in the correct folder, as well as leaves an interpreter open after execution. Further, it will close any other open python windows you have that you might have neglected to close, as I frequently do.

Comment: for Python 3.5 the directory is a little bit more complicated. This works for me: `C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

Comment: Update: this works for me too: `py -3 -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`. Helpful link to understand the `py -3` command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912063/how-do-i-run-python-2-and-3-in-windows-7

Comment: @GabrielStaples Can you post the `py -3` method as its own answer?

Comment: Tried all answers and all options within those on this page, all I have been able to get is a cmd window open up with different present working directory locations! None of them actually executed my python program from the Notepad++ from where I launched python using F5. Please help!

Comment: this worked for me: cmd /k "c:\python36\python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"". Note the extra quotes around the whole statement that's sent to cmd.

Answer (score 48):

@[Ramiz Uddin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702586/how-to-execute-a-python-file-in-notepad#comment1908592_1702605) definitely deserves more visibility :

- Open Notepad++
- On the menu go to: *Run* → *Run.. (F5)*
- Type in: `cmd /K python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

Comment: This works and is easier to configure IMO. Also add -i for the window to stay open 


cmd /K python -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"

Comment: It's worth noting this solution requires adding Python to your PATH. It works by opening the Command Line and typing `python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

Comment: Doesn't work on Python 3. For that see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48528175/4561887

Comment: this calls cmd window. can we call powershell instead?

Answer (score 24):

Here is what's worked for me:

Open notepad++ and press F5. You'll get a little popup box:

[image: Pop up box for entering the program to run]

> Type: ***C:\Python27\python.exe -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"*** for Python 2.7.
>
> and then ***Save As...***, and pick your own key combo to start it each time you want to run something

Comment: This is a nice concise answer and I've referred my interns to it when they go to set up NPP for Python development. But they were consistently having trouble understanding where to type the command, so I added a graphic to reinforce your (clear to me) instructions.   
They also had some trouble getting the fact that the first part of the command, `C:\Python27\python.exe` had to vary to reflect where their own Python was installed but that the second half,`-i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`, was magic that needed to be typed just as is.

Comment: Works as a charm for me with windows11 and python 3.10.2.

Answer (score 17):

I also wanted to run python files directly from Notepad++.
Most common option found online is using builtin option [`Run`](https://image.prntscr.com/image/kbmWDIm2Q1SQogwzkQ-yiQ.png). Then you have two options:

1. Run python file in console (in Windows it is [Command Prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)) with code something like [this](https://image.prntscr.com/image/x3Xb9yBEQxmq3zHvkZ0vKQ.png) (links: [image] [image] [image]):

   ```
   C:\Path\to\Python\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
   ```

   (If your console window immediately closes after running then you can add [`cmd /k`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) to your [code](https://image.prntscr.com/image/l0zwsjEvSoqXsf7S3N0VhQ.png). Links: [image] [image] [image]  [image]) This works fine, and you can even run files in [interactive mode](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i) by adding [`-i`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i) to your [code](https://image.prntscr.com/image/FSXucVQ6QYWAvu0ecFlOEQ.png) (links: [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]).
2. Run python program in [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html) with code something like [this](https://image.prntscr.com/image/I4BBwBQHS_yyQIz4GVUZgg.png) (links: [image] [image] [image] [image], in these links `C:\Path\to\Python\Lib\idlelib\idle.py` is used, but I am using `C:\Path\to\Python\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat` instead, because `idle.bat` sets the right current working directory automatically):

   ```
   C:\Path\to\Python\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
   ```

   Actually, this doesn't run your program in [IDLE Shell](https://image.prntscr.com/image/2kUyYT0vQaaWuuVUOO11Ag.png), but instead it opens your python file in [IDLE Editor](https://image.prntscr.com/image/2kUyYT0vQaaWuuVUOO11Ag.png) and then you need to click [`Run Module`](https://image.prntscr.com/image/OeU3MGuyR5isEu8nSVD2Ew.png) (or click F5) to run the program. So it opens your file in [IDLE Editor](https://image.prntscr.com/image/2kUyYT0vQaaWuuVUOO11Ag.png) and then you need run it from there, which defeats the purpose of running python files from Notepad++.

   But, searching online, I found option which adds '-r' to your [code](https://image.prntscr.com/image/XPRYyVKMT5WRWYok4ZzXdg.png) (links: [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]):

   ```
   C:\Path\to\Python\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat -r "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
   ```

   This will run your python program in [IDLE Shell](https://image.prntscr.com/image/2kUyYT0vQaaWuuVUOO11Ag.png) and because it is in IDLE it is by default in interactive mode.

Problem with running your python files via builtin [`Run`](https://image.prntscr.com/image/kbmWDIm2Q1SQogwzkQ-yiQ.png) option is that
each time you run your python file, you open new console or IDLE window and lose all output from previous executions. This might not be important to some, but when I started to program in python, I used [Python IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html), so I got used to running python file multiple times in same [IDLE Shell window](https://image.prntscr.com/image/2kUyYT0vQaaWuuVUOO11Ag.png). Also problem with running python programs from Notepad++ is that you need to manually save your file and then click [`Run`](https://image.prntscr.com/image/kbmWDIm2Q1SQogwzkQ-yiQ.png) (or press F5). To solve these problems (AFAIK[*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/afaik)) you need to use Notepad++ Plugins. The best plugin for running python files from Notepad++ is 
[NppExec](https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec). (I also tried [PyNPP](http://mpcabd.xyz/notepad-plugin-to-run-python-scripts/) and [Python Script](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/). [PyNPP](http://mpcabd.xyz/notepad-plugin-to-run-python-scripts/) runs python files in console, it works, but you can do that without plugin via builtin [`Run`](https://image.prntscr.com/image/kbmWDIm2Q1SQogwzkQ-yiQ.png) option and [Python Script](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) is used for running scripts that interact with Notepad++ so you can't run your python files.) To run your python file with [NppExec](https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec) plugin you need to go to [`Plugins -> NppExec -> Execute`](https://image.prntscr.com/image/LGa84GASQme8vBYmMVL8_A.png) and then type in something like [this](https://image.prntscr.com/image/PzYNQjgyRXGzJXbx5CFekA.png) (links: [image] [image]):

```
C:\Path\to\Python\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

With [NppExec](https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec) you can also save your python file before run with [`npp_save`](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec/blob/master/NppExec/doc/NppExec/NppExec_Manual/3.7.html) [command](https://image.prntscr.com/image/Bj2-nlYOQ32xAo8EOe-bZg.png), set working directory with [`cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"`](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec/blob/master/NppExec/doc/NppExec/NppExec_Manual/4.4.html) [command](https://image.prntscr.com/image/a85o6uUERYiWsQGlpTXIag.png) or run python program in [interactive mode](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i) with [`-i`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i) [command](https://image.prntscr.com/image/FFTAoUN7RB2vnWrHxhaBsg.png). I found many links ([image] [image] [image] [image] [image]) online that mention these options, but best use of [NppExec](https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec) to run python programs I found at [NppExec's Manual](https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec/tree/master/NppExec/doc/NppExec/NppExec_Manual) which has chapter [`4.6.4. Running Python & wxPython`](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec/blob/master/NppExec/doc/NppExec/NppExec_Manual/4.6.4.html) with this [code](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec/blob/master/NppExec/doc/NppExec/NppExec_Manual/4.6.4.html):

```
npp_console -  // disable any output to the Console
npp_save  // save current file (a .py file is expected)
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"  // use the current file's dir
set local @exit_cmd_silent = exit()  // allows to exit Python automatically
set local PATH_0 = $(SYS.PATH)  // current value of %PATH%
env_set PATH = $(SYS.PATH);C:\Python27  // use Python 2.7
npp_setfocus con  // set the focus to the Console
npp_console +  // enable output to the Console
python -i -u "$(FILE_NAME)"  // run Python's program interactively
npp_console -  // disable any output to the Console
env_set PATH = $(PATH_0)  // restore the value of %PATH%
npp_console +  // enable output to the Console
```

All you need to do is copy this code and change your python directory if you use some other python version (e.g.[*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/e.g.) I am using python 3.4 so my directory is `C:\Python34`). This code works perfectly, but there is one [line](https://image.prntscr.com/image/WjlWk5yeQQ2ns6PCbAC6Fw.png) I added to this code so I can run python program multiple times without loosing previous output:

```
npe_console m- a+
```

[`a+`](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec/blob/master/NppExec/doc/NppExec/NppExec_Manual/4.1.html) is to enable the "append" mode which keeps the previous Console's text and does not clear it.

`m-` turns off console's internal messages (those are in green color)

The final code that I use in NppExec's Execute window is:

```
npp_console -  // disable any output to the Console
npp_save  // save current file (a .py file is expected)
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"  // use the current file's dir
set local @exit_cmd_silent = exit()  // allows to exit Python automatically
set local PATH_0 = $(SYS.PATH)  // current value of %PATH%
env_set PATH = $(SYS.PATH);C:\Python34  // use Python 3.4
npp_setfocus con  // set the focus to the Console
npe_console m- a+
npp_console +  // enable output to the Console
python -i -u "$(FILE_NAME)"  // run Python's program interactively
npp_console -  // disable any output to the Console
env_set PATH = $(PATH_0)  // restore the value of %PATH%
npp_console +  // enable output to the Console
```

You can [save your NppExec's code](https://image.prntscr.com/image/TkpeRWF2Qi23uYHG3tX_Bw.png), and assign a shortcut key to this NppExec's script. (You need to open [Advanced options of NppExec's plugin](https://image.prntscr.com/image/GTer9TIjREGOIdjO1e_Tlw.png), select your script in the [`Associated script`](https://image.prntscr.com/image/-Hqfc0uaTyyhndWtWVyYBQ.png) drop-down list, press the [`Add/Modify`](https://image.prntscr.com/image/wioxb-siT-2lbPLzpdD2kg.png), restart Notepad++ , go to Notepad++'es [`Settings` -> `Shortcut Mapper`](https://image.prntscr.com/image/VOhY1FQhRB_OWQG5YOSXlg.png) -> [`Plugin commands`](https://image.prntscr.com/image/qImOByNbQn2Ap12befDTyg.png), select your script, click [`Modify`](https://image.prntscr.com/image/7ZtfYcsvQIClmHRfUEhU2A.png) and [assign a shortcut key](https://image.prntscr.com/image/Qi-S1OfbRzi-tS5Ei_zSJA.png). I wanted to put `F5` as my shortcut key, to do that you need to change shortcut key for builtin option [`Run`](https://image.prntscr.com/image/kbmWDIm2Q1SQogwzkQ-yiQ.png) to something else first.) Links to chapters from [NppExec's Manual](https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec/tree/master/NppExec/doc/NppExec/NppExec_Manual) that explain how to save you NppExec's code and assign a shortcut key: [`NppExec's "Execute..."`](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec/blob/master/NppExec/doc/NppExec/NppExec_Manual/3.6.html), [`NppExec's script`](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec/blob/master/NppExec/doc/NppExec/NppExec_Manual/3.7.html).

P.S.[*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postscript): With NppExec plugin you can add `Highlight Filters` (found in [`Console Output Filters...`](https://image.prntscr.com/image/TpUnykZIQD66lt2EUyELkA.png)) that highlight certain lines. I use it to highlight error lines in red, to do that you need to add `Highlight masks`: `*File "%FILE%", line %LINE%, in <*>` and `Traceback (most recent call last):` like [this](https://image.prntscr.com/image/eAdOrWUaQ4yi1FxPXEv_lg.png).

Comment: As of 2018, this is the best and most complete answer.

Comment: @JimmyHe: also as of 2021.

Comment: Love your styling links as small, round images. Going to start using it myself. Very meticulous answer, by the way.

Comment: This answer should be accepted the best

Answer (score 15):

First **install Python from** https://www.python.org/downloads/

Run the installer

** **IMPORTANT** ** 
Be sure you check both :

- Install launcher for all users
- Add Python 3.6 to path

Click install now and finish the installation.

Open notepad++ and install **plugin PyNPP** from Plugin Manager. I'm using N++ 6.9.2

Save a new file as new.py

Type in N++

```
import sys

print("Hello from Python!")
print("Your Python version is: " + sys.version)
```

Press Alt+Shift+F5

Simple as that.

Comment: trick to change the shortcut: search for the shortcut (not the name). Disable the one that could conflict.

Comment: Optional: to simply run the script (any script, not just python) you can use the plugin RunMe (but if you run a python the python console won't appear)

Answer (score 15):

On the menu go to: "Run" --> "Run..." (or just press <kbd>F5</kbd>).

## For Python 2 type in:

```
py -2 -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

## For Python 3 type in:

```
py -3 -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

## References:

To understand the `py` command better:

```
py -h
```

Another helpful link to understand the `py` command: [How do I run python 2 and 3 in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912063/how-do-i-run-python-2-and-3-in-windows-7)

Thanks to [Reshure for his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1702605/4561887) that got me on the right track to figure this out.

Comment: Up. Using this with `CTRL + ALT + P` shortcut.

Answer (score 14):

All the answers for the Run->Run menu option go with the "/K" switch of cmd, so the terminal stays open, or "-i" for python.exe so python forces interactive mode - both to preserve the output for you to observe.

Yet in `cmd /k` you have to type `exit` to close it, in the `python -i` - `quit()`. If that is too much typing for your liking (for me it sure is :), the Run command to use is

```
cmd /k C:\Python27\python.exe  "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" & pause & exit
```

`C:\Python27\python.exe` - obviously the full path to your python install (or just `python` if you want to go with the first executable in your user's path).

`&` is unconditional execution of the next command in Windows - unconditional as it runs regardless of the RC of the previous command (`&&` is "and" - run only if the previous completed successfully, `||` - is "or").

`pause` - prints "Press any key to continue . . ." and waits for any key (that output can be suppressed if need).

`exit` - well, types the exit for you :)

So at the end, `cmd` runs `python.exe` which executes the current file and keeps the window opened, `pause` waits for you to press any key, and `exit` finally close the window once you press that any key.

Comment: this answer deserves to be on top

Comment: best solution I have seen so fare.

Comment: This is certainly the best method, clean and concise

Answer (score 7):

None of the previously proposed solutions worked for me. Slight modification needed.

After hitting F5 in Notepad++, type:

```
cmd /k "C:\Python27\python.exe $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

The command prompt stays open so you can see the output of your script.

Answer (score 6):

I use the NPP_Exec plugin (Found in the plugins manager). Once that is installed, open the console window (ctrl+~) and type:

```
cmd
```

This will launch command prompt. Then type:

```
C:\Program Files\Notepad++> **python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"**
```

to execute the current file you are working with.

Answer (score 6):

I wish people here would post steps instead of just overall concepts. I eventually got the cmd /k version to work.

The step-by-step instructions are:

1. In NPP, click on the menu item: Run
2. In the submenu, click on: Run
3. In the Run... dialog box, in the field The Program to Run, delete any existing text and type in: cmd /K "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
   The /K is optional, it keeps open the window created when the script runs, if you want that.
4. Hit the Save... button.
5. The Shortcut dialogue box opens; fill it out if you want a keyboard shortcut (there's a note saying "This will disable the accelerator" whatever that is, so maybe you don't want to use the keyboard shortcut, though it probably doesn't hurt to assign one when you don't need an accelerator).
   Somewhere I think you have to tell NPP where the Python.exe file is (e.g., for me: C:\Python33\python.exe). I don't know where or how you do this, but in trying various things here, I was able to do that--I don't recall which attempt did the trick.

Comment: I'm guessing Python is just in your path.  This works for me and this is why I didn't have to tell NPP where Python was (And I do not believe there is anywhere to tell NPP where Python is)

Answer (score 5):

My problem was, as it was mentioned by copeland3300, that my script is running from notepad++ folder, so it was impossible to locate other project files, such as database file, modules etc. I solved the problem using standard notepad++ "Run" command (F5) and typing in:

```
cmd /k  "cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" & python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)""
```

Python WAS in my PATH. Cmd window stayed open after script finished.

Answer (score 4):

No answer here, or plugin i found provided what i wanted. A minimalist method to launch my python code i wrote on Notepad++ with the press of a shortcut, with preferably no plugins.

I have Python 3.6 (64-bit), for Windows 8.1 x86_64 and Notepad++ 32bit. After you write your Python script in Notepad++ and save it, Hit F5 for `Run`. Then write:

```
"C:\Path\to\Python\python.exe" -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

and hit the Run button. The `i` flag forces the terminal to stay still after code execution has terminated, for you to inspect it. This command will launch the script in a cmd terminal and the terminal will still lie there, until you close it by typing `exit()`.

You can save this to a shortcut for convenience (mine is CTRL + SHIFT + P).

Answer (score 4):

I would like to avoid using full python directory path in the Notepad++ macro. I tried other solutions given in this page, they failed.

The one working on my PC is:

In Notepad++, press F5.

Copy/paste this:

```
cmd /k cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && py -3 -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Enter.

Answer (score 3):

There is one issue that I didn't see resolved in the above solutions. Python sets the current working directory to wherever you start the interpreter from. If you need the current working directory to be the same directory as where you saved the file on, then you could hit F5 and type this:

```
cmd /K cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"&C:\Users\username\Python36-32\python.exe -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Except you would replace C:\Users\username\Python36-32\python.exe with whatever the path to the python interpreter is on your machine.

Basically you're starting up command line, changing the directory to the directory containing the .py file you're trying to run, and then running it. You can string together as many command line commands as you like with the '&' symbol.

Comment: Notepad++ does not recognize your `CURRENT_DIRECTORY` as the directory of the code file.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer -- i've been struggling with the current directory for a while. I made a few mods tho: 

`cmd /K cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"&python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"&pause&exit` 
This combines all the elements of the previous answer.

Answer (score 2):

Extending [Reshure's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1702605/6743697)

1. Open **Run → Run...** from the menubar in Notepad++ (shortcut: <kbd>F5</kbd>)
2. In the given space, enter:

   ```
   "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"  -1
   ```
3. Click **Run**

ta da!

Comment: also for error handling wrap the whole code in a try except block,
import traceback outside the try except block(i really don't know if you can import traceback inside), and in the except part add,`traceback.print_exc();input()`

Comment: Could please provide the complete code?  I have no idea what you are talking about.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the many other answers about using a system-wide installation of a Python interpreter, there is also a Python plugin for Notepad++.  I've used it many times, and it works quite well.  You can even assign shortcut keys to run specific Python scripts.

It is open-source and gratis (free of charge).

The source code and plugin are located here:
https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript/

Answer (score 1):

I started using Notepad++ for Python very recently and I found this method very easy. Once you are ready to run the code,right-click on the tab of your code in Notepad++ window and select "Open Containing Folder in cmd". This will open the Command Prompt into the folder where the current program is stored. All you need to do now is to execute:

> **python**

This was done on Notepad++ (Build 10 Jan 2015).

I can't add the screenshots, so here's a blog post with the screenshots - http://coder-decoder.blogspot.in/2015/03/using-notepad-in-windows-to-edit-and.html

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++, go to **Run → Run...**, select the path and `idle.py` file of your Python installation:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.py
```

add a space and this:

```
"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

and here you are!

Video demostration:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJipYE1JT38

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested in passing arguments to cmd.exe and running the python script in a Virtual Environment, these are the steps I used:

On the Notepad++ -> Run -> Run , I enter the following:

```
cmd /C cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) && "PATH_to_.bat_file" $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
```

Here I cd into the directory in which the .py file exists, so that it enables accessing any other relevant files which are in the directory of the .py code.

And on the .bat file I have:

```
@ECHO off
set File_Path=%1

call activate Venv
python %File_Path%
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run your script via cmd and be in script-directory:

```
cmd /k cd /d $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) && python $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer running my python scripts on python native IDLE interactive shell rather than from command prompt or something like that. I've tried it, and it works for me. Just open "Run > Run...", then paste the code below

```
python  -m idlelib.idle -r "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

After that, you can save it with your hotkey.

You must ensure your desired python is added and registered in your environment variables.