# How do I run python 2 and 3 in windows 7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there a way to install python 3 over an installation of python 2 without ruining anything? The main issue is that I have code that runs by "python xxxxx.py abc123". Is there a way to change python 3 to be "python3 xxxx.py abc123"? The same command `python` is the conflict

Comment: It's certainly possible, as "installing python" is just extracting a bunch of folders. Just run the installers and you'll have a python26 and python32 folders in your C drive. Concerning the command, you'll need some fiddling with the environment variables every time you want to use the other, so maybe a short bash script to modify the PATH is needed?

Comment: http://j.mp/ZfKVrb maybe this will help

Comment: No fiddling needed from Python 3.3 on.

Comment: The duplicate question is older, and the answer is different because of that fact.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

There is a better way of coexistence/launching of Python 2 and Python 3 on Windows. The Python 3.3 introduced the *Python launcher for Windows* (see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/).

After installation of Python 3.3, the `py.exe` and `pyw.exe` is copied to your `c:\Windows` directory, and the associations are set for the `.py` extension so that it uses the launcher. By default, Python 2 is launched for `py script.py`. The `py -3 script.py` launches Python 3. (This also means that no path for Python must be added to the environment -- the `C:\Windows` already is in the `PATH`.)

The best of all is that `#!python2` in the script causes lauching via Python 2, the `#!python3` causes launching the script via Python 3. This way, you can use scripts for both versions of Python, and you can lauch them the unified way -- `py script.py` or by just clicking on the script icon.

There are more details but this is basically what you need.

**Update:** When using Python launcher for Windows, you can also launch your Python script from `cmd` window by typing `> script.py` (that is without explicitly typing `py`--the name of the Python launcher--in front of the script name) or even by typing the name without the `.py` extension (that is just `> script`).

This way, things start to resemble the Unix way of naming scripts (without the need for the extension); however, you still have to add the `.py` extension when creating the script file.

(Yes, it is a bit more messy than the Unix approach. This is the difference between the *"Think first!"* and the *"Sell first!"* approaches of developments of the OSes. Anyway, my kudos to the Python development team to squeeze the best out of the Windows -- by releasing the Python launcher for Windows.)

Comment: I don't see any py.exe or pyw.exe. But when I launch Python I get: `Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Which means python3 is trying to launch python2 stuff.

Comment: Actually the py.exe is in the C:\Python33. But if I try launching py -3, I get the same error as above.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: I cannot confirm that. I have just uninstalled all Python versions I had on my disk, physically removing also the C:\PythonXX (with site packages, etc.), physically removed also C:\Windows\py.exe and pyw.exe. Then I have downloaded and installed http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/python-2.7.6.amd64.msi (py.exe not added to C:\Windows), and then http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/python-3.3.2.amd64.msi -- py.exe and pyw.exe added to C:\Windows. What version of Windows do you have?

Comment: Windows 8. I'll try what you did later.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: Well, it could be different. I did it on Windows 7.

Comment: +1 Excellent description, thanks.  This question should be the one that comes up first in a Google search, unfortunately it's not.

Comment: Excellent and concise. For those who want more details (in non-PEP form), some have found what I posted here to be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13533958/1593924

Comment: Starting with a fresh copy of Windows 8.1, I installed Python 2.7.9 and then Python 3.4.3 (both with default options). Python 3 did indeed add py.exe and pyw.exe to C:\Windows, and everything works as described by @pepr. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if it would meet your needs, but you should take a look at virtualenv: http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/

This will let you create separate environments for Python 2 and 3 (using the -p flag). If your use case is something for which this wouldn't work, update the question with some more specifics and I'm sure you'll get other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you install python3 in a separate directory, you could also rename the python 3 executable to be python3.exe.

Comment: Renaming the `.exe` breaks the use of `py -3`, which was suggested by @pepr.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your environment variable to include your Python 3 or Python 2 path.