# Path import error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running python 2.7 on windows.  Both python27 and python27/scripts are added to the PATH, which I've verified on the command line.  I used easy_install to download SOAPpy, and I have a simple python program that calls `import SOAPpy` at the top.

On the command line, running

```
python sample.py
```

works, as does importing in the interpreter.  However running simply

```
sample.py
```

Tells me:

```
ImportError: No module named SOAPpy
```

I'm sure this is some sort of path error, but I don't understand what's going wrong.  What's the difference between these two calls and how do I fix the issue?  I'm sure this is a really newbie question but I'm not sure what to google.  The fact that it works in the interpreter is making me scratch my head.

Comment: Looks like a *different* Python interpreter has been registered to handle `.py` files. See http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable

Comment: Also see [Windows insists associating .py files with the wrong version of Python](http://superuser.com/q/606916).

Comment: If you have python 3.3 installed your issue is probably as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912063/how-do-i-run-python-2-and-3-in-windows-7/17245543#17245543 take a look at the accepted answer.

Comment: Indeed, looks like I had a python 2.7 install on a different drive that was executing the script.  Calling 'import site; print (site.getsitepackages())' helped me track down where the different environments were running from