# Only one version of python works

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.3

I have both python 3.3 and 2.7 installed on my computer. I am running windows 8.

For some reason only one version of python runs at a time — whichever is first in the path `control panel > advanced settings`.

If 3.3 is first in the path, 2.7 IDLE won't even open and vice versa. What should I do?

Comment: this question might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912063/how-do-i-run-python-2-and-3-in-windows-7

Comment: @e-sushi [IDLE](http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/idle%5Cindex.html) is a Python IDE.

Comment: the IDE 'IDLE' won't even open..

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for the heads-up. I wasn't sure on that one, which is why I asked instead of bluntly editing that too… good thing I didn't. ;)

Answer (score 0):

run manually and setup default interpreters

default: C:\Python27\python.exe

and C:\Python33\python.exe