# In CMD "python" starts Python 3.3, "py" starts Python 2.7, how do I change this?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, path

Brand new Python, just getting things set up and installed before I start messing around with things. My understanding is that there are some notable differences/incompatibilities between Python 2.7 and Python 3.3, though both versions are well used, so I thought it best to install *both* (In their own install directories).

When installing, I used the new 3.3 feature where the installer set the PATH variables for me, however this option is not present for 2.7. After installing both versions, I tried a quick test, opened command prompt, and typed `python` to bring up an interactive session, and as I hoped, it brought up python 3.3.

I am also aware of the shorter `py` command. However when I try `py` in command prompt, it brings up python 2.7. I can use `py -3` to bring up 3.3, but that makes it longer than it needs to be, and seeing as I will be dealing primarily with version 3.3, I would like `py` *and* `python` to both bring up a Python 3.3 interactive session.

I am somewhat familiar with Window's PATH system, but I can't see why this is happening. How can I set it up so that *both* `py` and `python`, when typed into a windows command prompt, will start a Python 3.3 interactive session unless otherwise specified, e.g. via something like `py -2`?

Thanks.

Comment: Trivia: By default—if it is not overwritten with the environment variable, the ini file or with the parameter—the Python launcher will always prefer Python 2 over Python 3 installations (if both are available). This is the case because in the source, the check for version 2 simply [comes first](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c3896275c0f6/PC/launcher.c#l445).

Comment: For me it is the opposite. `py` opens up python 3.8.2 and `python` opens up python 2.7.6

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`py` is the [Windows Python launcher](http://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher), and it can start *any* Python version.

On most systems `py` is configured to launch Python 2.7 by default if present (this is the default except for Python 3.6 and newer, where Python 3 will be run instead). You have two options if you want to change that:

1. Set an [environment variable](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them); `PY_PYTHON=3` will make `py` run the latest Python 3 interpreter instead.
2. Create a file `py.ini` in your application directory with the contents:

   ```
   [defaults]
   python=3
   ```

   This has the same effect as the `PY_PYTHON` environment variable. Typically, your application directory is found in `C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Application Data` or `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\py.ini`, depending on the Windows version.

You can also add a `#!` shebang line to your scripts (first line) to tell the launcher to use Python 3 when you doubleclick such a file:

```
#! python3
```

`py` can also be configured to use specific Python versions when you have multiple Python 3 interpreters installed.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I used the first option, as it seemed 'cleaner'.

Comment: the first line `#! python3` does not work with me, why?

Comment: @zhangxaochen this works for me on Win7: `#! /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Nice answer. For more details see pep-0397, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912063/how-do-i-run-python-2-and-3-in-windows-7/17245543#17245543 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/13533958/1593924

Comment: What if I want to use `python` instead of `py` my vscode extensions keep trying to use `python` and it returns not found

Comment: @Batman: I don't know how vscode extensions look up commands on Windows, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

"py" is the python launcher, you could choose which version to launch by adding params `-2` or `-3`, see the help notes below:

```
C:\> py -h
Python Launcher for Windows Version 3.3.2150.1013

usage: py [ launcher-arguments ] script [ script-arguments ]

Launcher arguments:

-2     : Launch the latest Python 2.x version
-3     : Launch the latest Python 3.x version
-X.Y   : Launch the specified Python version
```

e.g., on my machine, `py` starts python 2 by default, adding `-3` makes it start python 3:

```
C:\> py
Python 2.7.4 |Anaconda 1.5.0 (32-bit)| (default, Apr  9 2013, 12:19:24) [MSC v.1
500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

C:\> py -3
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: I understand how I can chose the version with arguments, but currently `py` with no arguments defaults to version 2.7, just like yours, whereas I would like it to default to version 3.3, as I will use 3.3 the most, and `py` is ever so slightly shorter than `py -3`. Is this possible?

Comment: @user2649607, I'd like make it a batch file or shortcut link, and then pin it to the task bar or start menu. Moreover, I'd like to bind the launch of the program to some hotkey using `autohotkey`, so that I could launch it just by pressing `ctrl+shift+p` (or whatever you like)