# hello world python program two version python on same machine

Tags: python, windows

I have installed python2.7 and python3.7.3 on same windows 10 laptop.
Now I am trying to run programmes separately.
On windows cmd I type

```
cmd>py -2 print 'hello world'
C:\Users\data\installation\python2.7\python.exe: can't open file 'print': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I tried running on powershell

```
PS> python2  print 'hello world'
python2 : The term 'python2' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python2  print 'hello world'
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python2:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`
```

I try to run on powershell

```
> py2 print 'hello world'
py2 : The term 'py2' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
```

verify that the path is correct and try again.
    At line:1 char:1
    + py2 print 'hello world'
    + ~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (py2:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

If I run on powershell just

```
> py -2 print "hello world'
```

I get following prompt `>>>` but nothing else

same is problem with

```
> py -3 print ('Hello World')
C:\Users\data\installation\python\python.exe: can't open file 'print': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`
```

my script file (`script.py`) is:

```
#! py -3
python --version
```

I read these questions:

- [How do I run python 2 and 3 in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912063/how-do-i-run-python-2-and-3-in-windows-7/17245543#17245543))
- [How to install both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809314/how-to-install-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-windows-7)

I expect *hello world* to be printed instead of this errors are coming.

Comment: when you work with Windows, check if you have path to your python inside system environments. Also, when you use different python versions, it's nice to have virtualenvs and manage runnable scripts with them.

Comment: how to have virtualenvs please give some link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the launcher or commands correctly.

The [`py` launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows), like the [Python command-line binary itself](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#command-line) do not take Python code directly. So your first line

```
py -2 print 'hello world'
```

doesn't work because you asked the Python executable to find a file named `print` to run as a Python script. You can instead use the [`-c` command line switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c) to run a line of Python code:

```
py -2 -c "print 'hello world'"
```

That tells the Windows console to start the process `py`, passing in the arguments `-2`, `-c` and `print 'hello world'`, respectively (the `"` around the last part keep the console from seeing the spaces as delimiters). The `py` launcher then finds the Python 2.7 binary, and runs it with the remaining arguments.

Switching to the Powershell attempts, the first one doesn't work because Windows doesn't know where to find a `python2` exectable:

> The term 'python2' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

There is no `py2` executable *either*.

Stick to using the `py` launcher, as the two questions you link to advice:

```
py -2 -c "print 'hello world'"
```

Your `script.py` file can't work, because everything past the first line, `#! py -3`, is *Python code*. `python --version` is not valid Python. This will work:

```
#! py -3
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```