# Python on Notepad++ : How to pass command line arguments?

Tags: python, windows, notepad++

"ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack - Learn Python the Hard Way Ex: 13"

This problem has been discussed a lot of times on this forum. Is there a way to pass on the arguments in the Notepad++ editor itself?

Writing the code in the Notepad++ editor and then executing it on python's default environment after providing the arguments should make this work - but can we directly pass the arguments from notepad++?

P.S - Just started with python - no prior knowledge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Execute a Python File in Notepad ++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702586/how-to-execute-a-python-file-in-notepad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing command line arguments can only be done on the command line itself.

Or you can call it via another Python program using os.system to execute command line arguments.

os.system : Execute the command (a string) in a subshell. This is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and has the same limitations

```
import os
os.system("Program_Name.py Variable_Number_Of_Arguements"
```

You could also use call from subprocess:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["Program.py", "Arg1", "Arg2"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

After writing code in Nodepad++,  click File > Open Containing Folder > cmd.

This will open up a cmd window where you can type a query like below:

```
python filename.py arguments
```

Comment: I'm not sure this quite addresses the question- it seems like this run Python through a separate `cmd` window rather than directly in Notepad++. It is a nice shortcut for that, though