# How can I sync Notepad++ and Python shell?

Tags: python, python-2.7, synchronization

I prefer Notepad++ for programming but python's shell is really a quick way to view immediate results. Running the program from inside of notepad and locating the file everytime is too much time consuming. Is there a way to sync these so when I hit the F5 key in notepad Python's shell would pop up and run the program?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702586/how-to-execute-a-python-file-in-notepad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [PyNPP](http://mpcabd.xyz/notepad-plugin-to-run-python-scripts/) plugin for Notepad++.

Comment: the PyNPP was exactly what I wanted but comparing the result of the result printed when the speed of a simple program using the interactive from notepad++ and from python's shell itself the results were drastically different. Why does it happen so?

Answer (score 1):

Notepad ++ is intended for most programming languages. You can install an extension so that you can use it directly. ****THIS IS A DUPLICATE****

[How to Execute a Python File in Notepad ++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702586/how-to-execute-a-python-file-in-notepad)
 Please check before you ask.

For your information this link can be helpful

http://mpcabd.xyz/notepad-plugin-to-run-python-scripts/

Comment: How? I have like 3 reputation!

Comment: Ok i use another stack exchange website and I have like 190 reputation i can get 100 for this one as soon i get that but thanks!