# Python: Running Code from Notepad++ to the Python Console

Tags: python, notepad++

I'm attempting a small coding project; a simple encryption program. I was wondering if I would be able to directly run my Python code from Notepad++, or if there is a different program that could do this task (preferably free). Not that I have to have said feature, it would just make things easier for me.

Sorry if this was an off-topic question. If so, I sincerely apologize.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The search term you're looking for is `IDE`.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702586/how-to-execute-a-python-file-in-notepad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a text editor that will run the code directly, then try [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Otherwise open up a command prompt, save the file (e.g. `simplencrypt.py`) and then run `python.exe simplencrypt.py` in the command prompt when you want to run it.

I don't think you will be able to run your code directly from Notepad++.

Comment: Good to know! I'm still a noobie, so I really appreciate the quick help!

Answer (score 2):

**Wing IDE** and **PyCharm** (*My favourite personally*) are really powerful IDE's that can run and debug your application all inside the same environment. Alongside features like auto-completion, support for documentation, version control support right out of the box, and multiple build configurations (there's way more features to list here!), they make writing and testing code more efficient.

Otherwise, you can always run your code via a shell, though the back and forth makes workflow less efficient.

The community edition is free, and very powerful still:
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/