# Why is sys.exit() causing a traceback?

Tags: python, cmd, exit, traceback

According to *[How to exit from Python without traceback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1187970/3357935)*, calling `sys.exit()` in a Python script should exit silently without a traceback.

```python
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

However, when I launch my script from the command line on Windows 7 with `python -i "exit.py"`, ([or from Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1702586/3357935)), a traceback for a [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) exception is displayed.

```bash
U:\>python -i "exit.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exit.py", line 2, in <module>
    sys.exit(0)
SystemExit: 0
>>>
```

Why is `sys.exit()` displaying a traceback when run from the Windows command line?

(For reference, I am using Python 3.6.4 on Windows 7)

Comment: You cannot. It's the way [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) is implemented.

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ Your link uses the Python 2 documentation. You should repost with the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

Comment: note that this isn't really a traceback. `SystemExit` exceptions don't have tracebacks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're running Python with the `-i` flag. [`-i` suppresses the usual special handling of the `SystemExit` exception `sys.exit` raises](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Python/pythonrun.c#L578); since the special handling is suppressed, Python performs the normal exception handling, which prints a traceback.

Arguably, `-i` should only suppress the "exit" part of the special handling, and not cause a traceback to be printed. You could raise a [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/); I didn't see any existing, related reports.

Comment: when using os._exit(0), you can exit "-i" without any traceback

Comment: @Matt.St: `os.exit` is a drastic move that exits without any cleanup. No `finally`, `__exit__`, `atexit`, `__del__`, etc. It's not likely to be appropriate here.

Comment: you are absolutely right @user2357112, but in case he want drastic move, it can work

Answer (score 4):

No exception shown:

```
python exit.py
```

and your program is terminated.

Run with `-i` option for interactive (*inspect interactively after running script*)  and the exception is shown:

```
python -i exit.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exit.py", line 2, in <module>
    sys.exit(0)
SystemExit: 0
>>>
```

because the interpreter keeps running.

> `exit([status])`
>
> Exit the interpreter by raising SystemExit(status).

Answer (score 1):

Because under the hood, `sys.exit(0)` raises a `SystemExit` exception.

Further reading [here](https://clalance.blogspot.com/2011/01/exiting-python-program.html)

<s>what you want is:</s>

```
os._exit(1)
```

Comment: `os._exit(1)` will suppress the traceback, but it will also suppress all exit cleanup and exit immediately. This can cause data loss.

Answer (score 1):

[As Matt_G says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48571297/3357935), `sys.exit(0)` is exactly the same as raising `SystemExit()`, which can be caught in higher level, which in your case is happening since you are using `-i`.

If you want to exit without traceback, there is `os._exit(0)` which calls a "C function" and exit immediately even in `-i` mode

as @user2357112 told me, `os._exit(0)` is drastic move that exits without any cleanup. No finally,  `__exit__`, `atexit`, `__del__`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the -i option. Try it without that and you won't get a stack trace.

```
$ python ptest.py
$ python -i ptest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ptest.py", line 3, in <module>
    sys.exit(0)
SystemExit: 0
```