# Running a python script in notepad ++ doesn't work and other posts doesn't work

Tags: python, notepad++, python-3.5

Recently, (Half an hour ago) I downloaded Notepad++ to code in rather than IDLE.

Just to see if everything works out I created this simple program to test

```
def test():
    print("hello")

test()
```

I ran it, and then a window opened up and closed instantly.

Assuming the answer to the problem I had was located here: [How to Execute a Python File in Notepad ++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702586/how-to-execute-a-python-file-in-notepad) I followed the instructions, I tried it and it didn't work. Then I copied the file path with shift-RBM instead for what was on the page and still comes up with an error message as before:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
An attempt was made to execute the below command.
-------------------------------------------------
Command: C:\Users\----\Desktop\Python
Arguments: 3.5\Python 3.5 (32-bit).Ink
"C:\Users\----\Desktop\test.py" -i
Error Code: 2
-------------------------------------------------
```

After this I came here and asked this question. Sorry if the answer is said elsewhere or is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have space in some folder names.

To fix this you need to use **"** before and after the path to python.

Example:

```
"C:\Users\----\Desktop\Python 3.5\Python 3.5 (32-bit).Ink" "C:\Users\----\Desktop\test.py" -i
```